# How to override global auth_basic in nginx

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication

I have a situation wherein we have set `auth_basic` in global level for all non live sites. Is it possible in Nginx to override this `auth_basic` in site specific file and apply `auth_basic` for site-specific path with new authentication password.

`auth_basic` in global level is set on `/etc/nginx/conf.d/auth.conf`

site-specific configuration lies on `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sitename.conf`

in nginx.conf I have:

```
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do it.

Quoting from the docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html#auth_basic

> Syntax:   auth_basic string | off;
>
> Default:  auth_basic off;
>
> Context:  http, server, location, limit_except

As you can see the directive itself can be defined at multiple levels (contexts), i.e. if you have it at global level you can disable it at server or even location level.

The same is true for the **auth_basic_user_file** directive http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html#auth_basic_user_file

So you can have **auth_basic**/**auth_basic_user_file** defined at a global level and have it overridden per individual site

*auth.conf:*

```
auth_basic global;                                                          
auth_basic_user_file <path_to_your_auth_file>;
```

*sitename.conf:*

```
auth_basic sitenamereal; # any name, actually you can omit it
auth_basic_user_file <path_to_your_site_specific_file>;
```

Comment: doesn't work as expected. the global user credentials always overrides the later ones.

Comment: could you share your config files reproducing it? + what's your nginx version?

Comment: Here's an example working for me with sample config files and detailed output, it would be nice if you could share yours: https://gist.github.com/ffeast/d21bb4751cc994f3ba48300458496f9f